# NSIS Installer Name

Tags: installation, nsis

Is it possible to set the nsis installer file generated when compiling the installer?

something like:

```
makensis /ExeFile:myInstall-v4.1.2.3.exe install.nsi
```

That would be keen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a symbol on the [command line](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html) using the /D switch like so:

```
makensis /DMyInstallerName="myInstall-v4.1.2.3.exe" install.nsi
```

Then in your install script:

```
!ifdef MyInstallerName
    OutFile "${MyInstallerName}"
!else
    OutFile "myInstall.exe"
!endif
```